# WTSEnumerateProcesses and Terminal Services Service

Tags: windows, winapi

My Windows Service occasionally reports the following error when calling [`WTSEnumerateProcesses()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The binding handle is invalid.

This is caused, I suspect, by the unavailability of the Terminal Services Service, even though I have the Terminal Services Service registered as a dependent service for my service.

I believe that even though the Terminal Services Service is running, it has not completed initialisation (or is shutting down) and is not capable of servicing any requests, resulting in the error.

I noticed the following in the reference documentation for [`WTSRegisterSessionNotification()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> When the Global\TermSrvReadyEvent global event is set, all dependent services have started and this function can be successfully called.

This does not appear in the documentation for `WTSEnumerateProcesses()`, but does it equally apply? Meaning an attempt to `OpenEvent()` on `Global\\TermSrvReadyEvent` would indicate that the Terminal Services Service is actually available?

---

Platforms: Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 7

Comment: The assumption appears sound, but you should probably still wait on the event for correctness, not merely check whether it exists.

Comment: @0xC0000022L, yep, thats what I meant. It appears sound to be me but I just want to sure.

Comment: @hmjd: Just curious if you ever observed this on an OS other than XP? In my tests I can only see this error right after boot on Windows XP in most of WTS* APIs. This seems to have been fixed under Vista and later OS.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: My experience showed that relying on the `Global\TermSrvReadyEvent` event causes more problems than it solves. For instance, you will not be able to open that event if your process runs under a non-admin user account, which creates additional ambiguity. The most reliable approach in my tests was to check `GetLastError` after WTS* API fails, see if it's `RPC_S_INVALID_BINDING` and if so, wait a short period of time and repeat the call again (provided that some time-out hasn't expired.) In other words, I big headache!

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to `OpenEvent(SYNCHRONIZE, false, L"Global\\TermSrvReadyEvent")` and wait for it.

All `WTS*` functions call the terminal services service (now known as the remote desktop services service) via RPC under the hood of the C API ([see the runtime interface protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc248570.aspx)).

In contrary to what c00000fd experienced, I never encountered issues with standard user accounts and said event object on Windows 7 and above.