# How to get username/SID from session id in Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I Want to get the username or SID from a session id value, how can I do that working from Window XP using the WinAPI?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`WTSQuerySessionInformation` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the Username and Domain (`WTSUserName` and `WTSDomainName` from `WTS_INFO_CLASS`).

This function is available as far back as Windows 2000.

Comment: is that function (WTSQuerySessionInformation) avaliable from Win2k? documentation says that it requires Vista or higher...

Comment: @Jac0b: the minimum supported client is Vista simply because all earlier operating systems are past end-of-life and hence not supported by definition.  If you [check the wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20100430183551/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838(VS.85).aspx) you'll find that it was originally supported as far back as Windows 2000.

Comment: One word of advice if you plan on using `WTSQuerySessionInformation` API on Windows XP during your service start-up after boot. Most of the WTS-* APIs have a bug in that they depend on terminal services sub-system to be loaded after boot, and if it isn't the WTS-* APIs may fail. This can be indicated if a WTS-* API fails and returns an error code `RPC_S_INVALID_BINDING`. In that case, one of your options could be to retry the call after a delay, and do so until a timeout is reached. Note that this bug was fixed starting from Vista.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a bug, the WTS*-APIs depend on the TS/RDS by virtue of what they are intended to do. There's an event object you can wait for called `Global\TermSrvReadyEvent`, which is better than retrying upon error. c00000fd points out issues with that event in a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453322/wtsenumerateprocesses-and-terminal-services-service#comment55267525_11453322) to this other SO question, however I never experienced any with standard accounts since Windows 7.

Answer (score 5):

If you need this from a local system service then you can call [WTSQueryUserToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa383840(v=VS.85).aspx) to get *user token* from session ID, and then use method [similar to this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6b23fff0-773b-4065-bc3f-d88ce6c81eb0/get-user-sid-in-unmanaged-c?forum=vcgeneral) to retrieve a user SID (or user/domain name) using [GetTokenInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671(v=vs.85).aspx) API.